# Installing .NET 3.5 offline

Tags: windows-10, .net-framework

I searched on the web and I am trying to follow guides on how to install `.NET 3.5` on an offline machine. Steps that I followed:

1. Download official Windows 10 `.iso`
2. Mount it on `D:` drive 
   [File explorer which shows mounted Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OM4e.png)
3. Run `dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /All /Source:D:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess`
4. What I get back:

Error: 0x800f081f                                                                                                                                                                                                                               The source files could not be found.                                                                                    Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature.

I cannot solve this error, can someone help me out? I thought that `feature` naming might be bad, I opened mounted Windows `.iso` and navigated to `D:\sources\sxs` where I was able to find 4 files:

[File explorer showing files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3V7vT.png)

Comment: Have you tried one of these? https://sourceforge.net/projects/framework-3-offline/files/Windows%2010/

Comment: @TuxStash.de, it says: `An error occured while installing Microsoft .NET Frame work 3.5`. If in Settings I tick 'show instalation process`, then it suceeds, but I think it doesn't. my applications still complain that I don't have package and it is not listed on `Add or remove programs`

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows-10

Comment: @Moab, thanks but I went through this around 4 hours ago. The problem, that I cannot understand is, why all tools and cmd it self, cannot see `NetFx3` files although they path (source) is correct.